# Cordova/phonegap installation on new Windows 10 computer

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-pushplugin, phonegap-desktop-app

I've just got my new windows 10 PC and I am trying to install Cordova/Phonegap but I am facing some problem.

I did the next steps:

1. installed java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
2. installed nodejs C:\Program Files\nodejs
3. installed Android studio C:\Android\sdk (here the SDK MANAGER)
4. installed GIT
5. installed ANT C:\apache-ant-1.9.6
6. installed Cordova/phonegap (npm install -g cordova)

On the windows variable environment I set:

```
User Variable - PATH = C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs

SYSTEM Variable - ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\sdk
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS = C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools
ANT_HOME = C:\apache-ant-1.9.6
```

now when I creating a new project using:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

everything is good, next I do:

```
cordova platform add android
```

and that also works fine but the next command fails:

```
cordova build
```

I get the next error:

> C:\app_workspace\hello>cordova build Running command: cmd "/s /c
>   "C:\app_workspace\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65 Running:
>   C:\app_workspace\hello\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
>   C:\app_workspace\hello\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true Unzipping C:\Users\Shai Mor Yosef.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
>   to C:\Users\Shai Mor
>   Yosef.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:219)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:149)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:163)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
>           ... 3 more
>
> C:\app_workspace\hello\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                       ^  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\app_workspace\hello\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
>   C:\app_workspace\hello\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"  ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to build this project Error: cmd: Command failed
>   with exit code 1